# Cannot link with precompiled Lua binaries

Tags: c++, lua, g++

I am trying to compile an example program involving Lua, using MinGW.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <lua.hpp>

int main(void) {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_close(L);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I downloaded the LuaBinaries ZIP labeled "lua-5.3_Win64_dllw4_lib.zip", and unpacked it into my project. This is my file structure:

```
+- bin
+- include
|   +- lauxlib.h
|   +- lua.h
|   +- lua.hpp
|   +- luaconf.h
|   +- lualib.h
+- lib
|   +- liblua53.a
|   +- lua53.dll
+- src
|   +- Main.cpp
+- build.bat
```

The batch file is as follows:

```
g++ -c -v -Iinclude src/Main.cpp
g++ -v -o bin/main Main.o -Llib -llua53
del Main.o
pause
```

From what I have read, this setup should work, but the linker throws undefined reference errors on each call of a Lua function:

```
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `luaL_newstate'
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `luaL_openlibs'
Main.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `lua_close'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the 32bit dlls from LuaBinaries? Some MinGW distributions compile as 32bit by default (and some don't support 64 bit compilation at all) ...

Comment: ...I could have sworn that I tried that already. It worked though, so thanks!